# How to understand change of variables intuitively?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, intuition, change-of-variable

I've been trying to prove or have an intuitive understanding of the change of variables, and I tried it for the function $f(x)=x^2$ using $u(x)=x^2$, the transformed function then becomes $g(u)=u$.

Now I understand that a rectangle with a width dx in the first function transforms to a rectangle with a width of $2x\,dx$ in the second function (with the same height) and if I want to evaluate the area of the second, we must add $2x$ to the integral of $f(x)$. But if I want to evaluate the area of the first function using the second function, what does $du$ transform to in the first function?

Comment: Can you give a context?  Integration with one variable?
Integration with two or more variables?
Parametric equations?
Algebra II or Precalculus context?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please keep in mind, that we have never met you, have never met met your professor, have no idea what context you are coming from and many other similar concerns.
Simply because you most likely haven't yet studied the Jacobian or multivariable integration, doesn't make your context clearer.

Comment: You might try adding some integral signs, equations, etc.
For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I don't understand exactly what to edit, tell me please how my question could be paraphrased, and what do you mean by the word context?

Comment: The meaning of the question is pretty clear. OP wants an intuitive explanation of the change of variables formula for integration in single variable calculus. Briefly, if $u = f(x)$ then a rectangle of height $g(u)$ and width $du$ can also be described as having height $g(f(x))$ and width $f’(x) dx$. If $x$ ranges from $a$ to $b$ then $u$ ranges from $f(a)$ to $f(b)$. So $\int_a^b g(f(x)) f’(x) \, dx = \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} g \, du$. This formula can also be derived just by using the chain rule in reverse.

Comment: Rather, if $x=g(u)$ then $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm d x =\int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)} f(g(u))\,g'(u)\,\mathrm d u$ . So:  $$\begin{align}\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm d x &= \int_{a^2}^{b^2} f(\surd u)\,\dfrac{1}{2\surd u}\,\mathrm d u && x=\surd u \\ & = \int_{a^2}^{b^2} \dfrac{ u}{2\surd u}\,\mathrm d u\\ & =\tfrac 12 \int_{a^2}^{b^2} \surd u\,\mathrm d u\end{align}$$

Comment: @GrahamKempGracias  Can you edit your comment with the notation into the answer?  That is an excellent example.  
One approach is to rewrite the original into a composition of functions.  Let's examine different forms of the integrand and assume limits of integration will be adjusted accordingly.  Let's say f( x ) is actually composed of $f( x) = g(  u(x)  )$.

Also, I removed the multivariable calculus tag, because it only confuses the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches.

**We may express $f$ as a composition, $f(x)=g(u)$ where $u$ is a function of $x$.**

Let $g(y):=y$ and $u(x):=x^2$

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm d x &=  \int_a^b g(u(x))\,\mathrm d x\\&= \int_{u(a)}^{u(b)} ~g(u)\,\left(\dfrac{\mathrm d u}{\mathrm d x}\right)^{-1}\,\mathrm d u \\[1ex] &=\int_{a^2}^{b^2} u\cdot\dfrac 1{2\surd u}\,\mathrm d u\\ &= \tfrac 12\int_{a^2}^{b^2} \sqrt{ u\,}\,\mathrm d u
\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively:  **We express $x$ as a function of $v,$ so $x= h(v) =\surd v$**

$$\begin{align} \int_a^b f(x) \,\mathrm d x &= \int_{h^{-1}(a)}^{h^{-1}(b)} f(h(v))\,\dfrac{\mathrm d h(v)}{\mathrm d v}\,\mathrm d v\\ &=\int_{h^{-1}(a)}^{h^{-1}(b)} f(h(v))\,h'(v)\,\mathrm d v \\ &= \int_{a^2}^{b^2} f(\surd v)\,\dfrac 1{2\surd v}\,\mathrm d v\\ &= \tfrac 12\int_{a^2}^{b^2}\surd v\,\mathrm d v\end{align}$$